# How can i make a script pull my mouse cursor downwards at a different rate per second?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I can't figure out how to make the mouse pull down at a different rate for each second.

I've tried adding different sleep values which would change how hard my mouse would pull down throughout the script, but it doesn't work and it will only pull down in one set rate.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock" )then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            repeat
               MoveMouseRelative(0,1)
               Sleep(8)
               MoveMouseRelative(0,1)
               Sleep(7)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
end
```

I was expecting for the mouse to pull down at one rate, then pull down even harder a second later, but the results were just one fixed rate.

Comment: Lua can't do that, but the program that is exposing some functions/tools to the end-user (scripter) in lua can, meaning that your question is relative to a context

Answer (score 0):

Windows timer tick is 15-16 ms.
This means that `Sleep(1)`, `Sleep(2)`, ..., `Sleep(15)` are almost the same.
You should vary the amount of pixels you move your mouse.

```
local time0 = GetRunningTime()
repeat
   local dtime = GetRunningTime() - time0
   local dy 
   if dtime < 1000 then 
      -- during the first second we move mouse slowly: 1 pixel per tick
      dy = 1
   else
      -- after the first second we move mouse faster: 2 pixels per tick
      dy = 2
   end
   MoveMouseRelative(0,dy)
   Sleep(1)
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
```